# JTable getValueAt() se comportando diferente do esperado

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Tenho um JFrame onde existe uma JTable que exibe alguns dados. Quando o usuário selecionar alguns registros e clicar num certo botão, esses registros selecionados devem ser deletados.

Quando é selecionado apenas um registro, tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém a partir de dois registros começam a ocorrer problemas.

Digamos que eu decida apagar os seguintes registros:

[image: Registros selecionados]

Ao clicar em *Apagar registro(s) selecionado(s)*, o resultado é esse:

[image: Registros não apagados]

Como é possível perceber, os índices estão incrementando de 2 em 2: 1(0), 3(2), 5(4) ...

Esse é o código que estou usando para fazer isso:

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private DefaultTableModel tbModelo;

    private ArrayList<String[]> tableData = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    public NewJFrame() {
       tbModelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, new String[]{"ID", "Sequência", "Chave"}){
            //Torna as celulas da tabela readonly. Para permitir alterações retorne true;
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        initComponents();

        //Impede que o usuário reposicione as colunas na tabela
        jTable1.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

        preencheTabela();
    }

    private void preencheTabela(){
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            tbModelo.addRow(new String[]{String.valueOf(i),"0000", "1234"});
        }
    }

    //Desenha os elementos da UI
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        jTable1.setModel(tbModelo);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jButton1.setText("Excluir");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 452, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 275, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(30, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int qtdLinhasSelecionadas = jTable1.getSelectedRowCount();

        if(qtdLinhasSelecionadas > 0){
            //Armazena os indices das linhas selecionadas
            int[] linhasSelecionadas = jTable1.getSelectedRows();

            for(int linha : linhasSelecionadas){

                //Extrai o valor da coluna 'ID' na JTable independente da sua posição na tela
                String user_id = (String) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(linha), 0);

                tbModelo.removeRow(linha);

            }
        }

    }                                        

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;

}
```

Além disso, ao selecionar todos os registros e clicar em *Excluir*, recebe uma ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 >= 2
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:474)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:648)
at leitorabntkey.GerarChave.btApagarSelecionadoActionPerformed(GerarChave.java:399)
at leitorabntkey.GerarChave.access$700(GerarChave.java:37)
at leitorabntkey.GerarChave$7.actionPerformed(GerarChave.java:227)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Segundo a documentação do getValueAt ele deve retornar o valor da célula *linha x coluna*, como em uma matriz, mas aparentemente não é isso que acontece.

[Na resposta do Sage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076777/arrayoutofboundexception-when-getvalueat-from-a-table-that-sets-row-filter) é possível ver que o getValueAt retorna os valores das células baseadas no modelo da JTable (DefaultTableModel no meu caso) e no que eu pude identificar aqui, tanto o modelo quanto a view estão com a mesma estrutura (a JTable está com a reorganização de colunas desativadas).

Tem algo que eu não estou percebendo aqui? Ou algum outro caminho pra fazer o que pretendo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tente alterar a seguinte linha:

```
String user_id =  (String)tableChavesRegistradas.getModel().getValueAt(tableChavesRegistradas.convertRowIndexToModel(linha), 0);
```

O que tem que ser convertido é o indice interno da tabela para o equivalente no TableModel, você estava usando o método que faz o contrário.

E para evitar que estoure a exceção durante a exclusão de multiplas linhas, segue a solução para resolver o problema do `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
if(qtdLinhasSelecionadas > 0){

    int[] linhasSelecionadas = jTable1.getSelectedRows();

    for(int i = linhasSelecionadas.length-1; i >= 0; i--){

        String user_id = (String) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(linhasSelecionadas[i]), 0);

        tbModelo.removeRow(linhasSelecionadas[i]);
    }

}
```

Testando a alteração, o resultado foi esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segredo desse `for` é remover as linhas selecionadas dos indices maiores para os menores, pois internamente o `DefaultTableModel` reorganiza os índices das linhas restantes a cada remoção, estourando a exceção apresentada, caso tente excluir uma linha de indice maior. Removendo sempre o indice maior, isso não acontecerá.

Comment: Não resolveu. Pode ter algo a ver com o DefaultTableModel? Ou o modelo da tabela não interfere nesse tipo de operação? Editei a pergunta com um pouco mais de informação.

Comment: @FusRoDah061 parece que o problema apresentado agora é outro diferente do inicial, que era por causa da conversão do indice. Mas de qualquer forma, se você apresentar o trecho de sua tabela que seja possivel executar sem banco de dados(coloque alguns dados padroes para teste), já daria para sugerir solução. O meu de teste roda excluindo selecionado e sem lançar essa exceção ai.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o que obtive inserindo os dados a partir de um array de `Strings` e removendo esse dados. Os índices continuam sendo "bagunçados". Isso não faz sentido, pois debugando o programa, o array `int` que recebe o retorno do `getSelectedRows()` fica com os indices corretos, porém o `getValueAt` devolve um valor que não corresponde àquele índice.

Comment: @FusRoDah061 por isso a necessidade de você fornecer um [mcve] do seu programa. Eu fiz um exemplo bem parecido aqui e funciona normalmente. Sem ver o código do seu programa funcionando, não da pra achar o problema, vai ser apenas deduções.

Comment: Desculpe a confusão, é a primeira pergunta que faço aqui. Reformulei a pergunta e acredito que agora está mais direta.

Comment: @FusRoDah061 editei a resposta com a solução para os 2 problemas.